# Question about likelihood function in Bayes Rule and marginalization

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, likelihood, hierarchical-bayesian

The following is an instance of Bayes' Rule:

$$P(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon|\mathbf{X}) = \frac{P(\mathbf{X}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)P(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)}{P(\mathbf{X})}$$

I'm trying to understand the following break-down of the likelihood function:

$$P(\mathbf{X}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon) = \sum_{\mathbf{Y}}P(\mathbf{Z}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})P(\mathbf{Y})$$

$\mathbf{X}$ is a variable over strings of letters, e.g., `ace`, `fac`, `cc`. $\mathbf{Y}$ is a variable over matrices that contain only the values 0 and 1. This matrix is used to align the strings of letters.

So if $\mathbf{X}$ looks like this:

```
string1 ace
string2 fac
string3 cc
```

One possible $\mathbf{Y}$ is this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{string1}& 0&1&1&1\\
\mathrm{string2}& 1&1&1&0\\
\mathrm{string3}& 0&0&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Together $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ yield $\mathbf{Z}$, which is a matrix of aligned sequences:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{string1}& -&a&c&e\\
\mathrm{string2}& f&a&c&-\\
\mathrm{string3}& -&-&c&c\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

1s in $\mathbf{Y}$ correspond to letters from $\mathbf{X}$, and 0s to gaps. $\mathbf{Z}$ results from pairing a string with a matrix, i.e., from $(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})$. The likelihood function above I think says that the likelihood of $\mathbf{X}$ marginalizes over alignments, but I don't quite understand how.

In particular, I have the following questions about the structure of this equation:

1. How is it possible to have $P(\mathbf{Z}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)$ on the right-hand side but $P(\mathbf{X}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)$ on the left?
2. It seems like this equation marginalizes over both $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$. Is that correct? If not, what exactly is being marginalized over?
3. Is $P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})P(\mathbf{Y})$ equal to $P(\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})$?
4. Is $\sum_{\mathbf{Y}}P(\mathbf{Z}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon)P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})$ equal to $\sum_{\mathbf{Y}}P(\mathbf{Z}|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})$?

Generally speaking, I'm having trouble understanding how the right-hand side of the equation yields the likelihood function on the left-hand side.

Comment: Hi: It's probably best to first write out the marginal likelihoods for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ so that it's more clear on where things are coming from. My guess is that there's a typo in the very first expression because having $Z$ in there twice doesn't feel correct to me. But I could be wrong which is the reason for my suggestion.

Comment: In # 3, the thing on the left side is equal to $P(Z,Y | X)$ because $X$ is still being conditioned on. The general rule is, whenever you condition on something and also have it's marginal multiplying the conditional,, then that means that you can remove the thing being conditioned on and put it on  the left hand of the conditioned expression.

Comment: Are you sure that sum isn't over both $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: @jbowman Only $\mathbf{Y}$ is summed over. That's part of what I don't understand.

Comment: @mlofton Thank you. I added the complete equation, but I don't know how the marginal likelihoods for $\mathbf{X}$,  $\mathbf{Y}$, and  $\mathbf{Z}$ would be formulated.

Comment: ... and that $P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y,X})$ in the second equation isn't $P(\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{Y,Z})$?   (Just double-checking.)

Comment: $P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y},\mathbf{X})$ is also what the paper has.

Comment: This does not seem correct because there are two probability terms involving $\mathbf Z$ on the lhs.  Except, if $\mathbf Z=(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)$, $P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X})$ is a point mass.

Comment: @Xi'an Could you explain more about $P(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y},\mathbf{X})$ being a point mass? Also, do you mean rhs instead of lhs?

Comment: Yes I always confuse left and right..! Could you precise what you mean by "The value of $Z$ results from the pairing $(X,Y)$."

Comment: Could you also provide the reference to the paper you mention?

Comment: @Namenios: I'm gonna leave this to Xian and jbowman because I don't see where $Y$ and $Z$ are coming from so I would probably just add confusion.You're in good hands.

Comment: @Xi'an I unfortunately cannot link to the paper, since I have been asked not to share it. I did, however, expand the information presented in my question to make it clear how $\mathbf{Z}$ results from the pairing $(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$. Thank you for your help.